# I want the form action to be decided based on whether a check box has been selected or not using php

Tags: php, forms, authentication

If the check box below is selected I want the form to be processed by teacherprocess.php and if the checkbox is not selected I want the form to be processed by process.php. I'd rather this be done using PHP as I know some people do not support javascript in their browsers.

```
<form class="form-horizontal" action="#" method="post" name="form">
 <div class="control-group">
 <input class="input-block-level" type="text" id="username" name="username" placeholder="Username">
 </div>
 <div class="control-group">
      <input class="input-block-level" type="password" name="password" id="inputPassword" placeholder="Password">
    </div>
<input type="checkbox" name="teacher" value="I am a teacher">
<input type="submit" name="submit2" value="Student"  class="btn btn-info">
</form>
```

Comment: You could have the form post to a single page and include process/teacherprocess based on whether the checkbox is checked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Send the form to an intermediate PHP page:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" action="selector.php" method="post" name="form">
```

Then decide, based upon the checkbox being checked, which page to execute:

```
<?php
// selector.php

if (isset($_POST['teacher'])) {
     require ('teacherprocess.php');
} else {
     require ('process.php');
}
```

Disclaimer: I didn't try that.

Answer (score 0):

if you want php to do this. Here it goes

```
<form class="form-horizontal" action=" teacherprocess.php" method="post" name="form">
```

in teacherprocess.php check

```
if(!isset($_POST['teacher']))
header('Location: process.php');
```

Comment: Post variables won't carry over after a redirect.

Comment: you can extract it and set in variables before reedirecting